# Cut/paste rows to new sheet with certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need to move rows to a new sheet based on certain criteria. I found a very helpful discussion on here and it's almost exactly what I need, but the rows need to be deleted from the master sheet. The code that I've been using is this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fr33M4cro()

Dim sh33tName As String
Dim custNameColumn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim stRow As Long
Dim customer As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetExist As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet

sh33tName = "Sheet1"
custNameColumn = "I"
stRow = 2

Set sh = Sheets(sh33tName)

For i = stRow To sh.Range(custNameColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    customer = sh.Range(custNameColumn & i).Value
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, customer, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If sheetExist Then
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    Else
        InsertSheet customer
        Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn
    End If
    Reset sheetExist
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyRow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, custNameColumn As String)
Dim wsRow As Long
wsRow = ws.Range(custNameColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
sh.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
ws.Rows(wsRow & ":" & wsRow).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Reset(ByRef x As Boolean)
x = False
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSheet(shName As String)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = shName
End Sub
```

Any insight would be helpful, as I am very new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CopyRow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, custNameColumn As String)
Dim wsRow As Long
wsRow = ws.Range(custNameColumn & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Rows(wsRow).EntireRow.Value = sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Value
sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Note: The `ws.` in front of `Rows.Count`. Also, since you just want values, you can set the ranges equal to eachother.  This way, you bypass using the clipboard and it's a little faster.

Note: Since you're going to be deleting rows, in the loop that calls this sub, I recommend starting at the *end* and working your way toward the top:

`For i = sh.Range(custNameColumn & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to stRow Step -1`

That should work.  Otherwise, add `i = i - 1` to the end of the `CopyRow` sub, and make `i` global.

If you only want Columns A-M (1 through 13), you would do:

`ws.Range(ws.cells(i,1),ws.cells(i,13)).Value = sh.Range(sh.Cells(i,1),sh.Cells(i,13)).Value`

(I may have that backwards, or the `i` switched, but you should get the idea).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How would I edit this to just cut/paste values for columns A-M?